# How to create CQ5 Web page using Adobe Illustrator (.ai) file

Tags: adobe, aem, dam

I am new to Adobe cq5. Went through many online blogs and tutorials but could not get much. Can any one describe a way how I can create an HTML page from Adobe Illustrator (.ai) file containing images and font, required for web page.
I have installed CQ5 instance on my system but don't know how to work with AI files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a Web Developer with Adobe CQ knowledge.  Can I ask what your skill level is? Are you a developer?  Adobe CQ can be a challenge for the best developers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put you can't. For starters CQ5 is a modular CMS in that you drag in various components to build a page up. You have page templates that contain the basics of a page such as the header and footer but you don't create entire pages in one go so to speak. You build them up from reusable components.

Second you can't automatically convert an illustrator file to a webpage, you need a web developer to translate it into HTML, Javascript, JSP's and CSS. Also CQ5 can require quite a bit of back end coding in Java so that is something to keep in mind.

CQ5 is really an enterprise CMS so depending on your needs it might be worth taking a look at something like [Wordpress](https://wordpress.com/) although you still wont be able to simply upload an AI file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Illustrator (.ai) to build graphics for use within an AEM web site. You place those graphics in the the AEM DAM (Digial Asset Manager). You can then use those assets. For example:

1 - reference them in web pages.
2 - build components that use them. See http://scottsdigitalcommunity.blogspot.ca/2013/04/creating-gallery-components-that.html

As a new user, I recommend that you read this: http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/onboardAEM.html.

From that link - you will find a section about creating your first AEM site. Its a must to walk through to learn AEM.

You will also find other articles that will show you how to perform tasks - like creating OSGi services.